# changing just the time in a datetime using a number from another column in the same dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe something like this below, with the date format in the day column as d-m-y:

```
AL = (['1','10-12-2022','2022-12-17 00:00:00'],
['1','10-12-2022','2022-12-17 00:00:00'],
['1','7','2022-12-17 00:00:00'])
    
Data = pd.DataFrame(AL,columns = ['Hour','Day','Day2'])
```

where the dtypes are as follows:

```
Day               object
Day2              object
Hour              object
dtype: object
```

This is just a slice of my actual df, which is much bigger. The goal is that I want to change the hour of the datetime entries to be whatever number is in the hour column but the problem is I have this anomalous entry that is repeated throughout that causes errors. How best to deal with it?

So far I tried just this, but i get an error when it tries to convert the anomalous entry.

```
df_long['Day3']= pd.to_datetime(df_long['Day']) + pd.to_timedelta(df_long['Hour2'])

error: time data "7" doesn't match format "%d-%m-%Y", at position 6. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
```

My ideal output would be that the new column contains datetime entries like the following, after using the hour entry from the first column;

```
10-12-2022 01:00:00
```

date format = dd-mm-yyyy

I would like to know in general, what is a good way of selecting and then editing specific entries in a df column whilst ignoring others?

Comment: do you expect other formats for the datetime string, besides YYYY-MM-DD and DD-MM-YYYY ?

Comment: Corrected and updated ambiguity in date format. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking me if I expect other datetime string formats.

Comment: I'm asking because this is a crucial step in preparing the data. pandas cannot automagically infer the format for *any* input string. You'll need to make some specifications, e.g. by providing specific formats via the `format` keyword.

Comment: sure, that's clear enough, but are you asking because I've used two variations and you wonder if there are more in my df before you prepare an actual useful comment or just because you're assuming I might think pandas is magic? 

In my attempted solution I'm using  to_datetime twice and I couldn't get it to work with an argument specifying     format = '%d-%m-%Y'. I assume that's because it will only accept format as an argument once.

Comment: That was just for clarification, no worries. IIUC, answer below might work. Otherwise, if you encounter multiple, non-standard datetime formats, you'll need to extend the parsing step, e.g. by calling pd.to_datetime multiple times in sequence, each time filling NaT values that could not be parsed in the previous step.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve your goal by using a specific `format` to parse non-standard datetime string formats and keyword `errors` set to `'coerce'` to ignore invalid datetime strings. EX:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Hour", "Day", "Day2"],
    data=(
        ["1", "10-12-2022", "2022-12-17 00:00:00"],
        ["1", "10-12-2022", "2022-12-17 00:00:00"],
        ["1", "7", "2022-12-17 00:00:00"],
    ),
)

# Day column has non-standard format, so we specify a specific one to avoid ambiguities
df["Day"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Day"], format="%d-%m-%Y", errors="coerce")
# Day2 column has ISO 8601 format, so we can safely let the parser infer the format
df["Day2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Day2"], errors="coerce")
# now add the hour column after parsing with appropriate unit
df["Day3"] = df["Day"] + pd.to_timedelta(df["Hour"].astype(int), unit="h")
```

```
print(df)
  Hour        Day       Day2                Day3
0    1 2022-12-10 2022-12-17 2022-12-10 01:00:00
1    1 2022-12-10 2022-12-17 2022-12-10 01:00:00
2    1        NaT 2022-12-17                 NaT
```